# Does this $\left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right)^{-n}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, ratio

> $\left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right)^{-n}$

Does this sequence converge to $0$ by the ratio test?  Using the ratio test I get $-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3} \lt 1$

I tried to double check my results in wolfram which basically tells me the sequence diverges to $\infty$

Comment: Let $a_n$ be your expression. You *can* see by a calculation how $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ behaves as $n\to\infty$. It is actually a constant $\gt 1$, so we have divergence. However, the direct approaches in the current answers are much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does diverges because we have
$$\left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right)^{-n}=\left[\left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}\right)^{-1}\right]^{n}=\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^{n}$$
Which, because $3^2=9$ and $2^2=4$ we have $2<\sqrt{7}<3$, the important fact being $\sqrt{7}<3$ making $\left|-3/\sqrt{7}\right|>1$. Thus it diverges.
**Side Note** I wouldn't recommend resorting to things like the ratio check to see if a expression diverges as $n\to\infty$ because things like the ratio test are used to check if infinite series converge, and although an infinite series converging implies is summand going to zero, a summand can still go to zero without the series converging.

Comment: I don't understand where you got the  $3^2$ and $2^2$ from?

Comment: I just used it to approximate $\sqrt{7}$ within a suitable range for completing the problem. We have $4<7<9$ so if we take the square root of each term in the inequality we get $2<\sqrt{7}<3$ which allows us to see that $3/\sqrt{7}$ will be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's to the power $-n$, so you should consider reciprocal. Note that for $a^n$ to converge to $0$, we must have $|a| < 1$, not just $a<1$.